# How to change connection object

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, oledbconnection

I am trying to change the data connection string for 60 connections in an excel file through excel vba

tried everything

```
For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    Dim conString As String
    conString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL.1;Data Source=vp-pd-sql;Initial Catalog=Viewpoint;"
    conn.OLEDBConnection.Connection = conString
Next conn
```

> Get 1004 runtime error

Comment: @Tom  - why should it be outside?

Comment: When you use `Dim` it is declaring the variable and if it is inside the loop you will be attempting to re-declare it which shouldn't be done in many cases. Should you need to redeclare a variable use `ReDim`. However I have only ever used that for dynamically sized arrays.

Comment: @Vityata You're right - there is no reason to declare it outside of the loop. Personally, I think it is easier to read outside but that is my preference which isn't a justification.

Comment: @dasche - it is not trying to redeclare it. It is declared once and it stays. The `ReDim` is used [explicitly with arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement), not with any other type.